# SUMIF IN ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

me have teh following tables,

```
Game    date    win
A   01-Jan-20   25157
A   02-Jan-20   5904
A   03-Jan-20   15653
A   04-Jan-20   11204
b   01-Jan-20   14835
b   02-Jan-20   31355
b   03-Jan-20   32161
b   04-Jan-20   31809
c   01-Jan-20   43830
```

me need one more column which is going to add all teh win for same date.

```
Game    date    win   Total Win
A   01-Jan-20   25157   83822
A   02-Jan-20   5904    37259
A   03-Jan-20   15653   47814
A   04-Jan-20   11204   43013
b   01-Jan-20   14835   83822
b   02-Jan-20   31355   37259
b   03-Jan-20   32161   47814
b   04-Jan-20   31809   43013
c   01-Jan-20   43830   83822
```

so teh total win is all teh win on same date 25157+14835+43830=83822.
How can me write this query.

Answer (score 3):

With SUM() window function:

```
select t.*,
       sum(t.win) over (partition by t."date") "Total Win"
from tablename t
order by t.Game, t."date"
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8ae065ca3a72b65b0738b12df4f6df49).
Results:

```
> GAME | date      |   WIN | Total Win
> :--- | :-------- | ----: | --------:
> A    | 01-JAN-20 | 25157 |     83822
> A    | 02-JAN-20 |  5904 |     37259
> A    | 03-JAN-20 | 15653 |     47814
> A    | 04-JAN-20 | 11204 |     43013
> b    | 01-JAN-20 | 14835 |     83822
> b    | 02-JAN-20 | 31355 |     37259
> b    | 03-JAN-20 | 32161 |     47814
> b    | 04-JAN-20 | 31809 |     43013
> c    | 01-JAN-20 | 43830 |     83822
```